# command yarn start not found after cloning the project from github

Tags: reactjs, firebase, yarnpkg

i cloned a project from github .
when i try to run yarn it  successfully install the required packages .
but when i try to run yarn start i get error . please check below screenshot .
i searched alot and i get to know that package.json dont have a start object so i copy paste many ones from internet after looking for solutions but none of them is working .
i will be thankful if u help me to fix my bug .
[image]
[image]

Comment: Pls, run using this command `npm run dev`.

Comment: yeah kanti i fix my this issue by running npm run dev . Btw Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to upgrade your package.json file.

1. Follow the below steps and run the commands
2. First run "npm i" or "yarn" command
3. If you use npm:

   ```
   "npm i react react-dom react-router-dom react-scripts"
   ```

   Or If you use yarn:

   ```
   "yarn add react react-dom react-router-dom react-scripts"
   ```

Above command will install the latest packages in your project.

4. Make sure this script have in your package.json file:

   ```
   "scripts": {
   "start": "react-scripts start",
   "build": "react-scripts build",
   "test": "react-scripts test",
   "eject": "react-scripts eject"
   },
   ```
5. Now run the "yarn start" or "npm start" command.

I hope this will work. 100%

Answer (score 0):

normally when create new project, at "package.json" there is lines like this:

```
 "scripts": {
"start": "react-scripts start",
"build": "react-scripts build",
"test": "react-scripts test",
"eject": "react-scripts eject"
},
```

try to add manually

> "start": "react-scripts start",

Comment: i already tried this one also but its not working . error Command failed with exit code 1. i get this error

Comment: This package has not got a start script so may be you can add manually a start script but it can be change according to package. Did you run "yarn test"?